# HP 2140 screen resolution stuck at 1024x576

Tags: lubuntu, display, hp, intel

I installed Lubuntu on a HP2140 mini PC. Everything is working perfectly, except for the screen resolution. According to the specs it can do 1366x768.

I tried setting this resolution with xrandr, with both ctv and gtf to get the Modeline. But when I try to add the mode, it gives me:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  30
  Current serial number in output stream:  31
```

It's such a shame, because if I upgrade it with SSD and a little more RAM it could be a nice little mini book.

lspci gives me:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GSE Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
```

Answer (score 0):

What exact model do you have? There where both 1024x576 and 1366x768 models of the HP mini 2140. Might be a stupid question, but I often don't remember which screen I've got on my thinkpad... :)

Comment: I remembered that the original Windows XP ULCPC had that 1366x768 resolution, but now you made me doubt myself. I'm not sure where I can find this info on the laptop itself though. Maybe I should try and install windows xp again.

Comment: Check the product number or serial number (normally) on the back of the computer. Go to [hp support site](http://support.hp.com/us-en/) and search for this number and you'll be able to find the specs for it.

Comment: The models are described in [this document](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=c04142182)

Comment: But there is no 1366x768 model listed..

Comment: I tried searching by serial number. I could fetch information about warranty, but not about the specific hardware. I know Dell stores all information like this by service tag, but apparently HP doesn't. The document you provided says `10.1-inch diagonal 16:9 HP Illumi-Lite LED scratch-resistant display (1024 x 576 or 1366 x 768)` on page 3.

Comment: Yes, I saw yesterday that they started to "retire" models from their support pages. Bad practice. But in the document I linked to each model is described (starting on page 7), but among these I couldn't find any 1366x768 model. The document could be incomplete, of course. Check the SKU numbers in the document and see if your PC has a matching one. They are normally on the sticker with the serial number.

Answer (score 0):

I have an **HP 2140** too, with **2GB** of **ram**, and I had an SSD inside. 
And the **bottleneck** of this system is the **Atom processor**. 
Which was indicated by a Win 7 system test. 
I had a dual boot with Lubuntu. It's only the start-up time that gets shortened, it doesn't make the system faster or extend battery life.
**I took** the **SSD out** and going to reinstall Lubuntu again.
Just to let you or other people know, who get tempted to install an SSD in this system.